# How to put this long equation in a two column document?

Tags: equations, two-column

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\xi_2=\omega^2 \psi_{0} \sin \omega t\left \{&\sum _ { n = 0 } ^ { \infty } \frac { ( - 1 ) ^ { n } 4 } { \pi ^ { 3 } ( 2 n + 1 ) ^ { 3 } } \left[\frac{h^{2} \sin ((2 n+1) \pi z / h) \sinh ((2 n+1) \pi x / h)}{\cosh ((2 n+1) \pi L / 2 h)}\right.\right.\\
&\left.+\frac{L^{2} \sin ((2 n+1) \pi x / L) \cosh ((2 n+1)(z-(h / 2)) \pi / L)}{\sinh ((2 n+1) \pi h / L)}\right] \\
&+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} 4 L}{\pi^{2}(2 n+1)^{2}}\left(\frac{\omega^{2}}{\omega_{n}^{2}-\omega^{2}}\right)\left[\frac{h}{2}-\frac{2 L \tanh ((2 n+1) \pi h / 2 L)}{\pi(2 n+1)}+\frac{g}{\omega_{n}^{2}}\right] \\
&\left.\times \frac{\sin ((2 n+1) \pi x / L) \cosh ((2 n+1)(z+(h / 2) \pi / L)}{\cosh ((2 n+1) \pi h / L)}\right\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I have this long equation that I want to put in a `\twocolumn` class document. I've tried to wrap this with `\begin{figure*}` but it pushed the equation to the end. Other solutions destroyed the numeration of the equations and I dont want to do that. What can I do to solve this?

This equation goes at the beginning of a new page.

EDIT:
An example of what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eurosym} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\title{1}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\twocolumn
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}[!htbp]
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\xi_2=\omega^2 \psi_{0} \sin \omega t\left \{\sum _ { n = 0 } ^ { \infty } \frac { ( - 1 ) ^ { n } 4 } { \pi ^ { 3 } ( 2 n + 1 ) ^ { 3 } } \left[\frac{h^{2} \sin ((2 n+1) \pi z / h) \sinh ((2 n+1) \pi x / h)}{\cosh ((2 n+1) \pi L / 2 h)}\right.\right.\\
&\left.+\frac{L^{2} \sin ((2 n+1) \pi x / L) \cosh ((2 n+1)(z-(h / 2)) \pi / L)}{\sinh ((2 n+1) \pi h / L)}\right] \\
&+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} 4 L}{\pi^{2}(2 n+1)^{2}}\left(\frac{\omega^{2}}{\omega_{n}^{2}-\omega^{2}}\right)\left[\frac{h}{2}-\frac{2 L \tanh ((2 n+1) \pi h / 2 L)}{\pi(2 n+1)}+\frac{g}{\omega_{n}^{2}}\right] \\
&\left.\times \frac{\sin ((2 n+1) \pi x / L) \cosh ((2 n+1)(z+(h / 2) \pi / L)}{\cosh ((2 n+1) \pi h / L)}\right\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The first code has a & before `\sum`, and that is why it's not compiling (but somehow overleaf auto-corrected it). I want the `\sum` to be aligned with the & below(and now I don't know how to do this either).

What I need is the text before and after the equation be in two columns but the equation itself pass thorugh both columns.

Comment: Hi, @Michael, and welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). It is always easier for everyone to one exactly what issue you are dealing with when you provide a compilable example. By the way, your equations seems a little bit messy. I could not compile it independently of `twocolumn`.

Comment: a brief example is added, in case it helps to understand the issue.

Comment: just add `&` on the first line so it starts `\xi_2&=` then the whole thing fits in one column